# if my height is 5'9" what mtb should I buy?

Tags: frames, bike-fit, shopping, weight

I am rookie and I want to know about mountain bike and want to know that if my height is 5.9 which mountain bike works for me. So guys please help to know about mountain bike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably need a medium but that can depend on the brand and riding style. For example my previous 2 MTBs (trek, commencal) where medium but my current one (canyon) is small.

Have a go at canyon's interactive tool: http://www.canyon.com/_en/tools/pps.html

Comment: Unless you're buying an Canyon, this interactive site is really not useful. You can search all day long on the web, but until you ride multiple bikes, you wont know what YOU like.

Comment: Yes, and I've already said that (see the "that can depend on the brand" part). I gave out this tool because it's interactive and gives light on how different measurements (e.g torso, inseam) can affect MTB size choice.

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible to determine via the internet - the fit of a bike depends on inseam, arm length, and a multitude of other physical measurements as well as personal preference and the type of bike (there are large variations in types of mountain bikes even) and riding style.

Read this [article](http://sheldonbrown.com/frame-sizing.html) and [this article](http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/fitting.htm) for more details on what goes into bike fitting. Note that its really more of an art than a science.

Go to your local bike shop and ask for a bike fit and try out lots of bikes in realistic riding conditions and find one that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a bike pro fit you, but you have some options.

- Test ride:
  drive some around in the parking lot to get a feel for the bike. A good shop will work with you and not just try to take your money.
- Demo a bike: find a dealer that will let you demo a bike - that is actually take a bike (or 2) on your local trails to ride.

See this [video](http://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/bike-fit.html) by REI on bike fit: http://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/bike-fit.html

I'm **5'10 and was riding medium** for a longtime, the last bike I
   purchased (a 29er), I actually felt much more comfortable on the
   **large frame**. This goes against conventional wisdom that says you
   might want a slightly smaller frame on a 29er. With that being said, the bike geometry can be different depending on the bike, which will require different seat height and stem lenght (to name a couple) just to make you feel comfortable.

Go in to a local shop and ask lots of questions. Also, you may be tempted to buy online to save a couple hundred dollars. Honestly, having the option to go into the shop you bought is so much better, they usually work with you and will give you a free tune up. My local shop is awesome!

Comment: A medium and large are highly dependent on product line, even within the same manufacturer - the terms are essentially useless aside from inventory purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a bike shop and try them out. I'm 5'9" and usually ride a 'medium' in surly sizes, which is about 16-18 top tube.  However, your body proportions are likely a bit different, so the only way is to ride a few and get a feel.  Keep in mind, what feels good cruising on the road, might be different from what feels good on singletrack.

What you really want to do is find a bike that has the right sized frame that fits well and refine the fit from there. You can always swap out your stem and adjust your seatpost to get the fit right.

After having a couple bike fits done, I recommend finding a bike shop that can do a fit for you (a lot of shops might consider giving you a discount fit if you're buying the bike from them). It's not mandatory, but it can yeild big improvements in some cases. I don't even know how long I rode on my cross bike with a stem that was too long and caused pain in my wrists and discomfort in my back.

Fitting a bit different than the technique for road bikes.  Here's a good guide to bike fit suited for mountain bikes that will give you a bit more info for details of a good fit.

http://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/article/technique-perfect-mountain-bike-fit-29498/

Comment: FWIW, a lot of Surly's have long top tubes for their size. Just goes to show that it depends a lot on the models you're considering as well as your proportions.